# Xilinx Verilog `define macro to replace wire/reg name

Tags: macros, preprocessor, verilog

We're trying to do something like following in verilog:

```
`define MY_SUFFIX suffix
wire prefix_`MY_SUFFIX;
assign prefix_`MY_SUFFIX = 1'b0;
```

However, the pre-processor doesn't seem to do the right substitution. There is a syntax error on the `assign` line ("syntax error near 'suffix'), but there is no syntax error if the `assign ...` line is commented out but the `wire ...` line isn't.

Going to simulate this with the `assign...` line commented out (to avoid syntax errors) gives the compilation error "prefix_ is an unknown type".

There's clearly something we're missing, but that behavior doesn't make sense!

Answer (score 1):

Running this with various simulators at edaplayground gives mixed results:
http://www.edaplayground.com/x/A84

Fundamentally I don't believe Verilog is required to honor spaces (or lack thereof) around a macro.  Where it's not working it was probably expanded as:

```
wire prefix_ suffix; // space in middle, syntax error
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what I was afraid of. Which sadly makes it less useful for this kind of meta-programming than I would like.

Comment: For anything more complicated than using generate loops, generally I have had to go to using some outside tool or language.  I would look at VPP to see if it does what you need, or use Perl/Python to generate dynamically.  Migen is a good Python code generation library.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled upon this post because I had the same problem. My solution was to create a macro that also accepts the prefix as an input.
It does not look very nice but it works:

```
`define MY_SUFFIX(name) ``name``suffix
wire `MY_SUFFIX(prefix_);
assign `MY_SUFFIX(prefix_) = 1'b0;
```

Or for better readability:

```
`define CONCAT(a,b) ``a``b
`define MY_SUFFIX suffix
wire `CONCAT(prefix_, `MY_SUFFIX);
assign `CONCAT(prefix_, `MY_SUFFIX) = 1'b0;
```